# Finding the computational complexity of an algorithm

Tags: math, optimization, computer-science, big-o

**Algorithm:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2*n; i += 2)  
    for (int j = n; j >i; j--)  
        foo();
```

*I want to find the number of times foo() is called.*

```
# of foo() calls for the second loop as i changes:

1st loop:   n - 0
2nd loop:   n - 2
3rd loop:   n - 4
nth loop:   n - f(x); f(x) = last term +2; where f(0) = 0

  Total # calls = Summation(n - f(x)) from [i = 0] to [i = n/2 (where f(x) == n)]
= Summation(n) - summation(f(x))
= (n/2)(n+n)/2 - (n/2)(0 + n)/2
= n^2/2        - n^2/4
= n^2/4
```

I've done all the work but my equation always gives values that are a bit off:

When n = 5: Recorded foo() calls is 9, but my equation gives 6.
When n = 6: Recorded foo() calls is 16, but my eqution gives 9.

**What have I done wrong?**

Comment: the algorithm makes sense, cant understand your results, please post code that doesn't work with the results you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The summation has n/2+1 terms; i=0 is the first term and i=n/2 is the last one!

**So you should have**

summation(n) = (n/2+1) (n+n)/2

and

summation(f(x)) = (n/2+1) (0+n)/2.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes an empirical approach works well.  See http://codepad.org/zpBDNkuj.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count(int n) {
  int i, j, times = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 2 * n; i += 2)  
    for (j = n; j > i; j--)  
      times++;
  return times;
}

int main() {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    printf("%2d%10d\n", i, count(i)); 
  return 0;
}

 0         0
 1         1
 2         2
 3         4
 4         6
 5         9
 6        12
 7        16
 8        20
 9        25
10        30
11        36
12        42
13        49
14        56
15        64
16        72
17        81
18        90
19       100
```

Looking at the output, you can make inferences from how T(n) is generated from T(n-1), T(n-2), and so on, and you can compose a recursive definition of T.  This appears to be the approach you have taken.

You might be able to get to a closed from faster by trying to figure out the pattern directly from the output.  For example, we see from the output that:

- When n is odd, T(n) is ceil(n/2) ** 2
- When n is even, T(n) is (n/2) * (n/2+1)

**ADDENDUM**

I've added a little to the codepad; see http://codepad.org/aEnFZ1Da

This shows that T(n) converges asymptotically to n^2/4.  This agrees with the answer you got.  Perhaps you were saying your results were a "bit off" because for small values of n you were not seeing exactly n^2/4.  This is fine.  What matters is that in the limit the complexity is n^2/4.  Of course, you can also just say THETA(n^2)....

Comment: Odd should be `(n+1)^2 / 4` and even should be `n/2 * (n/2 + 1)`.

Comment: what I did was make the function foo increment an "ActualCount" integer. Then I compared the ActualCount to the result generated by my complexity equation n^2/4. For the case of n= 5 the ActualCount was 9 while my equation came out to 6.

Comment: Ok; figured it out. Thanks for the alternate approach recommendation though, I'll see if I like that better =)